# Something like a for loop does not use pl / sql triangle printing, Is there a method that can use in the select clause?

Tags: sql

I would like to print something like this

```
    ***
    ** 
    *
```

I have some code in MySQL 
SELECT REPEAT('* ', @NUMBER := @NUMBER - 1);

Comment: What have you done so far? is there any code. If yes, post it. We don't give you code, we help with your code.

Comment: I try to similar method in oracle is exist ?

Comment: I also try using rpad()

Answer (score 0):

I find solution:

```
   select rpad('*', (3 - level + 1) * 2, ' *') from dual
   connect by level <= 3;
```